# Use mysql drivers with ejabberd without recompilation

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd

I have all the mysql .beam files needed for ejabberd. And I installed ejabberd via apt.
But when I try to copy those .beam files into `/usr/lib/ebin` directory and run ejabberd it echoes to ejabberd.log the following:

> =INFO REPORT==== 2012-05-31 09:46:02 ===
>       application: ejabberd
>       exited: {bad_return,{{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
>                            {'EXIT',database_module_missing}}}
>       type: temporary

What I'm doing wrong?

What's the correct way of adding mysql drivers to ejabberd apt installation?

Comment: source of beam files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEAM files used by ejabberd [are located in a different place](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/ejabberd/filelist) — try putting your files there.

As a side note: are you sure those BEAM files are really OK? Erlang is not too permissive when it comes to *binary* portability, so it's always advised to recompile the necessary code using the same release of Erlang as will run ejabberd on the target machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check which triggers this ERROR is staightforward. It checks if hardcoded list of modules is in Erlang VM path. Make sure that odbc files are there and that they have proper file ownership. Required files are:

```
check_database_module(odbc) ->
    check_modules(odbc, [odbc, odbc_app, odbc_sup, ejabberd_odbc, ejabberd_odbc_sup, odbc_queries]);
check_database_module(mysql) ->
    check_modules(mysql, [mysql, mysql_auth, mysql_conn, mysql_recv]);
check_database_module(pgsql) ->
    check_modules(pgsql, [pgsql, pgsql_proto, pgsql_tcp, pgsql_util]).
```